# When Apple test my macOS app they don't get permission to open a local Webbserver

Tags: electron, app-store, appstore-approval, httpserver, appstore-sandbox

I have created a macOS app with Electron.
The app runs without any problem if I build it and run it locally.
But when Apple tries to run they encounter a problem that gives them this error.

```
[2021-06-09 10:59:19.217] [info]  ----------> start_server
[2021-06-09 10:59:19.218] [info]  3000
[2021-06-09 10:59:19.221] [info]  Error while starting server:  listen EPERM: operation not permitted 0.0.0.0:3000
[2021-06-09 10:59:19.222] [info]  Error caught:  listen EPERM: operation not permitted 0.0.0.0:3000
[2021-06-09 10:59:19.222] [info]  Error stack :  Error: listen EPERM: operation not permitted 0.0.0.0:3000
```

I'm trying to start a http server with this code:

```
module.exports = {
    startServer: async () => {
        _port = await UtilityService.getPort();
        console.log(_port);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            httpServer.on('error', error => {
                console.log('Error while starting server: ', error.message);
                onError(error);
                reject(error);
            });
            httpServer.listen(_port, () => {
                console.log('HTTP Server listening on http://localhost:' + _port + '/');
                resolve();
            });
        })
    },
```

https://github.com/mattehalen/Scheduled-countdown/blob/master/src/server.js

Comment: Might have something to do with your entitlements file, does it have `com.apple.security.network.server` set to true?

Comment: No it didn't. I will try adding that and reupload it.

Comment: I did ad it to my entitlements files but that made it crash. Took it away and the same problem again. Updated Electron to the newset release and the same with electron-builder. Didn't help. I then added it back to ONLY entitlements not entitlementsInherit and now I get Gatekeeper Conformance issue.